# Prove of the Danes drop theorem in Banach Spaces

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, banach-spaces

I have searched a lot the prove of the Danes drop Theorem in Banach Spaces but I dont achievement find it. If anyone could tell me where I can read it or know the prove I will be grateful. The statement is the following:

Let $(X, || \cdot ||)$ be a Banach space. Let $A \subset X $ be a nonempty closed and $B \subset X$ a nonempty closed bounded and convex set such that
\begin{equation}
d(A, B) = \inf \{ || a - b ||: a \in A, b \in B \} > 0
\end{equation}
Then, for each $x_0 \in A$ there exists $x^* \in X$ such that:
\begin{equation}
x^* \in A \cap D(x_0, B) \hspace{.2cm}\text{and}\hspace{.2cm} \{ x^* \} = A \cap D(x^*, B)
\end{equation}
Note that the "drop" generated by $x \in X$ and $B \subset X$ is defined to be the set
\begin{equation}
D(x, B) := \{ tx + (1 - t)b: \hspace{.2cm}b \in B, t \in [0, 1] \}
\end{equation}
Update: The issue now, because of
the paper https://dml.cz/bitstream/handle/10338.dmlcz/106385/CommentatMathUnivCarol_026-1985-3_2.pdf is how the generalized K.M. Lemma (Lemma GKZ in paper) implies the Generalized Drop Theorem (the Danes' drop theorem here, Generalized drop theorem in the paper).

Comment: What does the notation $D(x_0, B)$ mean?

Comment: The "drop" generated by $x \in X$ and $B \subset X$ is defined to be the set $D(x, B) := \{ tx + (1 - t)b: \hspace{.2cm}b \in B, t \in [0, 1]\} $

Comment: I suggest drawing a 2D example to give you an idea for what $x^*$ should be.

Comment: ccI guess that $x^*$ must be in the border of A but I don't have idea of the prove.

Answer (score 1):

A possibility to find the proof would be a pdf-request via scinapse: https://scinapse.io/papers/73432139

A hint on how to prove it is in this paper by Danes: https://dml.cz/bitstream/handle/10338.dmlcz/106385/CommentatMathUnivCarol_026-1985-3_2.pdf

Another option would be to extract a proof from the generalization of Danes drop theorem to locally convex spaces which can be found here: https://www.researchgate.net/publication/254488994_Danes'_Drop_Theorem_in_locally_convex_spaces
which, at first glance, seems quite doable without too much time investment.

Comment: The proof does not appear in this paper. How the generalized K.Z. Lemma implies the Generalized drop theorem?

Comment: You are absolutely right, I should have been a bit more careful there.

Comment: I just get the related article, do you want it for trying answer?